# how to check equivalent in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I get some data from the server, and I want to compare it with something which I get from EditText.
my server-side is so simple:

```
<?php 
   echo "123456789";
?>
```

and my client side which is Kotlin is :

```
if (it==password){
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
```

'it' refers to Volley StringRequest response and 'password' is the text which is extracted from EditText like this:

```
val password=userPassword.text.toString()
```

but never these two become equivalent, even though I write exactly 123456789

Comment: What do `it` and `password` look like when you print them?

Comment: I get log and answer is : Log_wrongPass: pass=123456789 server=123456789

Comment: Any additional whitespace somewhere? If both are `123456789` then your check is fine and the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: exactly, I checked it manually, means, instead of server response I wrote: "123456789" and compared with user input, and it worked, all problem is in the response of the server. but my server-side is so simple! so what is the problem,

Comment: Can you print `it==password` to see if it is `true` or `false`? If the variables are both `String` the `==` operator should work.

Comment: I got the log, it prints false while both are equivalent!@DiegoMagdaleno

Comment: Can you post more code so we can better understand the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: although server returns exactly `"123456789"` but I don't know why volley response has white space at the end of the answer, so the answer was: `"123456789 "`

so I trimmed the end of the response string and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try `it.compareTo()` as the condition:

```
// it.compareTo(password) == 0
it.compareTo(password).compareTo(0)
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparable/compare-to.html

> `abstract operator fun compareTo(other: T): Int`
>
> Compares this object with the specified object for order.

Returns

- zero if this object is equal to the specified other object (`0`),
- a negative number if it's less than other (`-32`),
- or a positive number if it's greater than other (`32`).

Comment: No, wait! now it is true for all conditions

Comment: The compareTo method returns zero for equal strings, a positive value if the argument's ASCII value is smaller, and a negative value if the argument's ASCII value is greater.

Comment: This means `it > password`, that is very different from `it == password`

Comment: It would be really helpful to mention *why* you would try this. `==` doesn't necessarily work when the types are not the same, but comparison might.

Comment: @Tenfour04 It returns `Int` with value `0` when it matches. the documentation does not leave much to explain - and I won't spend any more time on down-voted answers.

Comment: What I meant was that you explained what it does, but not why you would ever want to use `compareTo(...) == 0` instead of simply `==`. Using `compareTo(0)` on the result of a `compareTo()` operation would just return that same result. I think you misunderstood my comment. My last sentence was the explanation that I think is missing from your answer. I meant `==` **alone** doesn't work for mismatched types but this answer of using `compareTo() == 0` is a workaround for that. I wasn't the downvoter. I found this helpful, but I had to search for the explanation elsewhere.